# Batch convert TIFF to PDF and add text

Tags: batch, pdf, imagemagick, tiff, image-conversion

I have a bunch of TIFF files that I am interested to convert to a single multipage PDF file, which should be easily achieved using ImageMagick.

However, I'm also interested in adding text to each image: a title. Is there some way I can add a text title to each image? I do not care if it's embedded in the TIFF itself or added as vector text on top in the PDF file.

I would prefer a Windows solution but I have Linux around if it helps.

Comment: imagemagick has watermarks/text effects.

Comment: Use a page template with latex (better results IMHO). Moreover with Linux it is quick to do a script that copies the header of the latex document (`head -n 20 template.tex > Mydoc.tex` if 20 is the number of lines), writes a page for each line of you text file, then the final part of the latex document, and compiles it (creates the pdf).  In the text file the list of the image names and captions for the the figures, one for line. You have as bonus the index of the figure too with a line written in the latex template. ;)

Comment: @Hastur that's a good idea. I haven't thought of that. My Latex skills are a bit rusty - any chance you can do a MWE as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you want add water mark to your images but without any of blur etc. You can use image software that is able to do that.

The one I know for free is [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) with [Batchwork extension](http://registry.gimp.org/files/batchwork.py).

Paid one are Photoshop or [uMark](http://www.uconomix.com) which is desired software for water marks.